# Pivot rows to columns without aggregate

Tags: sql, pivot

Trying to figure how to write a dynamic pivot sql statement.  Where `TEST_NAME` could have up to 12 different values (thus having 12 columns).  Some of the VAL will be Int, Decimal, or Varchar data types.  Most of the examples I have seen have some from of aggregate included.  I am looking to for a straight value pivot.

```
Source Table 

╔═══════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ TEST_NAME ║ SBNO ║  VAL  ║
╠═══════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ Test1     ║    1 ║ 0.304 ║
║ Test1     ║    2 ║ 0.31  ║
║ Test1     ║    3 ║ 0.306 ║
║ Test2     ║    1 ║ 2.3   ║
║ Test2     ║    2 ║ 2.5   ║
║ Test2     ║    3 ║ 2.4   ║
║ Test3     ║    1 ║ PASS  ║
║ Test3     ║    2 ║ PASS  ║
╚═══════════╩══════╩═══════╝


Desired Output 
╔══════════════════════════╗
║ SBNO Test1 Test2   Test3 ║
╠══════════════════════════╣
║ 1    0.304  2.3    PASS  ║
║ 2    0.31   2.5    PASS  ║
║ 3    0.306  2.4    NULL  ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `PIVOT` function requires an aggregation to get it to work.  It appears that your `VAL` column is a `varchar` so you will have to use either the `MAX` or `MIN` aggregate functions.

If the number of tests is limited, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select sbno, Test1, Test2, Test3
from
(
  select test_name, sbno, val
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for test_name in (Test1, Test2, Test3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6df9f/1).

In your OP, you stated that you will have an larger number of rows to turn into columns.  If that is the case, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(TEST_NAME) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT sbno,' + @cols + '
             from 
             (
                select test_name, sbno, val
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for test_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa69c/3).

Both versions will give the same result:

```
| SBNO | TEST1 | TEST2 |  TEST3 |
---------------------------------
|    1 | 0.304 |   2.3 |   PASS |
|    2 |  0.31 |   2.5 |   PASS |
|    3 | 0.306 |   2.4 | (null) |
```

Comment: Great answer, is it possible to use the same approach in C# ?

Comment: @Oliver There are ways to pivot in C# but I am not overly familiar with them.  I would suggest looking at some of the questions on SO about linq-to-sql with pivot.  There are several that can be found in a pivot search.

Comment: Let say if there are multiple entries for Test1,Test2 and Test3 for a particular SBNO, is there a way I can pivot that too?

Answer (score 6):

There is no any way to PIVOT without aggregating.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    TEST_NAME VARCHAR(10),
    SBNO VARCHAR(10),
    VAL VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO #table1 (TEST_NAME, SBNO, VAL)
VALUES ('Test1' ,'1', '0.304'),
       ('Test1' ,'2', '0.31'),
       ('Test1' ,'3', '0.306'),
       ('Test2' ,'1', '2.3'),
       ('Test2' ,'2', '2.5'),
       ('Test2' ,'3', '2.4'),
       ('Test3' ,'1', 'PASS'),
       ('Test3' ,'2', 'PASS')

WITH T AS
(
    SELECT SBNO, VAL, TEST_NAME    
      FROM #table1
) 
SELECT *
  FROM T
 PIVOT (MAX(VAL) FOR TEST_NAME IN([Test1], [Test2], [Test3])) P
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to ensure that the obligatory aggregation is only ever applied to a single record. In Excel for example the output could be:

[image: SO15674373 example]

where Row Labels includes at the bottom a column of cells with unique index numbers.