# Collecting multiple columns of aggregate data with a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to figure out if the query I'd like to do is at all doable or feasible in SQL or if I need to collect raw data and process it in my application.

My schema looks like this:

```
applications
================
id INT

application_steps
=================
id INT
application_id INT
step_id INT
activated_at DATE
completed_at DATE

steps
=====
id INT
step_type_id INT
```

Ideally, with this data in `application_steps`:

```
| id | application_id | step_id | activated_at | completed_at |
| 1  | 1              | 1       | 2013-01-01   | 2013-01-02   |
| 2  | 1              | 2       | 2013-01-02   | 2013-01-02   |
| 3  | 1              | 3       | 2013-01-02   | 2013-01-10   |
| 4  | 1              | 4       | 2013-01-10   | 2013-01-11   |
| 5  | 2              | 1       | 2013-02-02   | 2013-02-02   |
| 6  | 2              | 2       | 2013-02-02   | 2013-02-07   |
| 7  | 2              | 4       | 2013-02-09   | 2013-02-11   |
```

I want to get this result:

```
| application_id | step_1_days | step_2_days | step_3_days | step_4_days |
| 1              | 1           | 0           | 8           | 1           |
| 2              | 0           | 5           | NULL        | 2           |
```

Note that in reality there are many more steps and many more applications that I would be looking at.

As you can see, there is a *has-many* relation between `applications` and `application_steps`. It is also possible for a given step to not be in use for a particular application. I'd like to get the amount of time each step takes (using `DATEDIFF(completed_at, activated_at)`), all in one row (the column names don't matter). Is this at all possible?

Secondary question: To complicate things a bit further, I will also need a secondary query which joins `application_steps` with `steps` and only gets data for steps with a particular `step_type_id`. Assuming part one is possible, how can I extend it to filter efficiently?

NOTE: Efficiency is key here - this is for a yearly report, which equates to about 2500 `applications` with 70 different `steps` and 44,000 `application_steps` in production (not a lot of data, but potentially a lot when joins are factored in).

Comment: [may be this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16298859/319542).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a basic "pivoting" aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when step_id = 1 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_1_days,
       max(case when step_id = 2 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_2_days,
       max(case when step_id = 3 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_3_days,
       max(case when step_id = 4 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_4_days
from application_steps s
group by id;
```

You would have to repeat this for all 70 steps.

To do this only for a particular type of step:

```
select application_id,
       max(case when step_id = 1 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_1_days,
       max(case when step_id = 2 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_2_days,
       max(case when step_id = 3 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_3_days,
       max(case when step_id = 4 then datediff(completed_at, activated_at) end) as step_4_days
from application_steps s join
     steps
     on s.step_id = steps.id and
        steps.step_type_id = XXX
group by application_id;
```

Comment: should that `max` be `sum`?

Comment: @Lobo . . . I don't know if it should be `max()` or `sum()`, and it may not make a difference.  Which depends on the data and the business requirements.  When there is only one value expected per pivot column, I usually use `max()`.

Comment: @DanielVandersluis an aggregator is a must to avoid nulls; whether its `max()` or `sum()` depends on what @GordonLinoff mentioned.