# Pivoting with multiple column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am stuck in a complicated problem. I do know that it can be solved by pivoting but have no idea how to do it.

The data looks like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id | order_id | service |  head | coordinatior | contract |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1020    | 3        | 105     |   1   |    1         |     1    |
| 364277  | 1        | 105     |   0   |    0         |     0    |
| 364277  | 3        | 105     |   0   |    0         |     0    | 
| 367277  | 2        | 3763454 |   1   |    1         |     0    |
| 1020    | 1        | 3764142 |   0   |    1         |     1    |
| 1020    | 2        | 665443  |   0   |    1         |     1    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is how I'd like to have according to the order:

---

```
| user_id | service1 |  head1 | coordinatior1 | contract1 | service2  |   head2 | coordinatior2 | contract2 |  service3 |  head3 | coordinatior3 | contract3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1020    | 3764142  |   0    |      1        |    1      |   665443  |   0     |      1        |    1      |   105     |   1    |      1        |    1      |
| 364227  | 105      |   0    |      0        |    0      |   3763454 |   1     |      1        |    0      |   105     |   0    |      0        |    0      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right now I displayed 3 services as it will become a huge horizontal scrollbar but there can be max 10 services per user_id which mean it is possible that some users may have 4 services.

This is what I have for query.

```
SELECT user_id, service FROM table 
PIVOT (?) FOR order_id IN (0, 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

and I have no idea how to proceed forward. Any help?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

`select 
user_id
,max(case when order_id=1 then service end) as service_1
,max(case when order_id=2 then service end) as service_2
from 
table

group by user_id`

service_1,2..10 is the same.

Comment: thanks...after tweaking your query a bit for my use, it worked :-)