# stored procedure to create table from another tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have two tables which are Courses and Departments

the **Courses** table contains 2 attributes (CourseID,CourseName)

the **Departments** table contains 2 attributes either (DeptID,CourseID)

the department number 2 have 5 courses.

now ..
i want to make a stored procedure that creates a table contains the following attributes
**(DeptID,courseNo1,courseNo2,courseNo3,courseNo4,courseNo5)**
depends on the previous two tables

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate

Comment: no not duplicate, create a new table contains the ID of specific department and it's courses from both courses and departments tables