# How to pull the duplicate record in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have some records that looks like this.

[image]

I want to pull out as the following.

[image: Second Pic]

Is this possible?

I can only pull out the duplicate values but can't get that I want.

SELECT [COLUMN A] , COUNT([COLUMN A]) FROM [MYTABLE] GROUP BY [COLUMN A] HAVING COUNT([COLUMN A]) >1 ORDER BY [COLUMN A]

Anyone please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are there three "Column A" columns in your first graphic?

Comment: Your data example does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. You all are so fast. :D I added wrong grapic. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the desired result:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA
    , MAX(ColumnB) ColumnB
    , MIN(ColumnC) ColumnC
    , MAX(ColumnC) ColumnD
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY ColumnA
ORDER BY ColumnA;
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, I want to ask you another Q concerning with this.
If Column A has more than 2 times with different Column C, how should I do?

Comment: If you have more than 2 distinct values for Column C, you can consider "pivoting" the table. Check this related question out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Try in the 'Count()' sentence add the id or *
i.e.:

```
SELECT [COLUMN A] , COUNT(*) FROM [MYTABLE] GROUP BY [COLUMN A] HAVING COUNT(*) >1 ORDER BY [COLUMN A]
```

or

```
SELECT [COLUMN A] , COUNT(´id_col_A´) FROM [MYTABLE] GROUP BY [COLUMN A] HAVING COUNT(´id_col_A´) >1 ORDER BY [COLUMN A]
```