# oracle pivot without aggregation

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a requirement to transpose the column into header.

The Data values is

```
Column A Column B
-------- --------   
AA       B
AA       C
AD       D
```

The out put should look like this

```
AA  AD
--  --
B
C
     D
```

I tried with pivot but I'm not able to do it without aggregation.

Could someone help me out with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivot rows to columns without aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said, maybe you're after something like:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 'AA' col_a, 'B' col_b FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'AA' col_a, 'C' col_b FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'AD' col_a, 'D' col_b FROM dual)
SELECT CASE WHEN col_a = 'AA' THEN col_b END aa,
       CASE WHEN col_a = 'AD' THEN col_b END ad
FROM   sample_data;

AA AD
-- --
B  
C  
   D
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Since the values are limited I've also found a way to get the desired output through Oracle Decode