# Pivoting replicate values in a column to wide format without aggregating using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to the dataset described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate) and attempting for a solution also as described in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate) using R. However, I am not able to create the desired table without aggregating the data.

```
Day <-    c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
Treatment <- c("M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M3", "M3", "M1", "M1", "M2", "M2", "M3", "M3")
Values <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 2)

tx <- data.frame(Day,Treatment, Values)

    Day Treatment Values
1:    3        M1      2
2:    3        M1      3
3:    3        M2      5
4:    3        M2      7
5:    3        M3      7
6:    3        M3      9
7:    5        M1      3
8:    5        M1      3
9:    5        M2      5
10:   5        M2      5
11:   5        M3      7
12:   5        M3      2
```

I tried the following solution.

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(tx), Day~Treatment, value.var='Values')

   Day M1 M2 M3
1:   3  2  2  2
2:   5  2  2  2

spread(tx, Treatment, Values)

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 12 rows:
```

I would like to create the following output:

```
       Day   M1    M2    M3
 #1     3     2     5     7
 #2     3     3     7     9
 #3     5     3     5     7
 #4     5     3     5     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `Day` and `Treatment` create a unique ID column and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tx %>%
  group_by(Day, Treatment) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Treatment, values_from = Values) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

#    Day    M1    M2    M3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     2     5     7
#2     3     3     7     9
#3     5     3     5     7
#4     5     3     5     2
```

Comment: Marvelous! I spent the whole day for a solution, and you made it look so simple.